# THREE.JS point cloud - single Points are too close in rear part of the representation

Tags: three.js, point-clouds

I'm trying to build a webview for point clouds. I have a very large database with a huge scan from a Mobile Mapping System (laser scanner combined with GPS).
I already leaded the points I need with THREE.JS:

```
const vertices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < pointCloud.length; i++) {

        var coords = pointCloud[i];

        const x = (coords[0]-eastValue);
        const y = (coords[2]);
        const z = ((-1)*(coords[1]-northValue));
            
        vertices.push(x, y, z);

    }

    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );

    const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( {
        color: 0x888888,
        size: 0.01
    } );

    const points = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );

    scene.add(points);
```

[image: Example]

In the foreground I have the desired result. Since the points of the point cloud are still so close together in the background, it looks like one surface. The details (e.g. edges of houses, windows) care no longer visible.
Is there a possibility to mange this in THREE.JS? Or should I do this 'by hand' when selecting the points?

Comment: By default, all points in a point cloud are the same size. As the points get further away, even if they are the same 3D distance apart, the perspective effect will cause them to be projected closer together. You could create your own shader to adjust their size as hey get closer to/further from the camera, but that might require extra tweaks, like scaling-up your cloud to ensure enough space between points.

Comment: @TheJim01 The Problem is, that I use the minimum Size of a Pointsmaterial (0.01). If I adjust the size of the point cloud, I also have to change my point of view, to see the same scene. In the end I have the same Problem again

Comment: The point (no pun intended) is that with a perspective camera, as points get further from the camera, they are projected to the screen closer together. It's like drawing with a vanishing point: A line of a certain length will appear shorter (its ends closer together) the closer it moves to the vanishing point. So even though your points are evenly distributed in 3D space, "near" points are projected to the screen further apart, and "far" points are projected closer together. You could switch to an orthographic camera, but you'd lose your depth. Or write a shader to discard select "far" points.